# Do I need Integrity and crossorigin attributes in Locally Hosted Resources?

Tags: javascript, css, html, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap Using `integrity` and `crossorigin` attributes on it's CDN sources like

```
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

now my question is if I want to use sources locally from my own hosted server do I still need  those attributes or this will be good enough?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the short answer is No.

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Subresource_Integrity), Subresource Integrity is a security measure for CDNs in case it becomes compromised. It uses the hash to verify it is genuinely the CDN you requested.

Since they are local resources you are using, these attributes are not needed.